# Python requests: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I scraped a webpage (name changed in code here) as follows:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.samplewebpage.com')
```

Then I tried to write r.text to a file as follows:

```
f = open ('filename', 'w')
f.write(r.text)
f.close()
```

I get an error as:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 158691: character maps to <undefined>
```

r.encoding shows UTF-8. How to resolve the above?

Have also tried the following:
- few other random webpages and am able to run the code without any error for most.
- instead of r.text used r.content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') but same error as above

My environment/system specifications:

- Python 3.6.4
- Windows 8.1 Pro, 64 bit
- Default IDLE as installed from https://www.python.org.
- Tried with a script in Atom as well, but same error.

Suspecting console encoding mismatch as I read in another similar problem on this forum, I reconfirmed from that the Atom console is set to UTF-8, though I believe console encoding is not the problem here, as I want to write to a file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly specifying the file's encoding:

```
f = open ('filename', 'w', encoding='utf8')
f.write(r.text)
f.close()
```